# Terragrunt - reusing modules more effectively

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I've been trying to restructure my terraform modules in a way that things can be reused.
The issue I'm trying to resolve here is to avoid creating new tf modules with just one or two new attributes that are meant for certain setup.

The current structure:

```
├── services
│   ├── ec2
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   ├── ec2_with_fixed_ip
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl (2)
│   └── terragrunt.hcl (1)
├── tf_moodules
    └── ec2
    │   └── main.tf
    └── ec2_with_fixed_ip
    │   └── main.tf
    └── ec2_with_root_block_device
        └── main.tf
```

I've also been looking at using the [terraform-aws-ec2-instance](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules) git repo as the source in my terragrunt script. This way, I won't have to manage the tf modules at all. But I'm not sure how I should write my terragrunt.hcl to point to the GitHub repo and peg to a certain version.

Is this a recommended way of doing things? or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Content inside the terragrunt.hcl (1)

```
remote_state {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    encrypt        = true
    bucket         = "my_bucket"
    key            = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "ap-southeast-1"
    dynamodb_table = "tf-locks"
  }
}
```

Content inside the terragrunt.hcl (2)

```
terraform {
  source = "git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance.git//?ref=v2.15.0"
}

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

inputs = {
  ami = "ami-0123456789abcd"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  disable_api_termination = false
}
```

Tried the above setup, but facing the issue with missing backend "s3" block

Comment: You're already doing it the right way! You could consider using a git source (`git::git@github.com:terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance.git//?ref=v2.15.0`) but that's mostly a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out more with the help of this link

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/311

In my case, even though i've defined the remote_state block in my terragrunt root file, the backend block is not generated in the cache folder after running the terragrunt command.

What needs to be done is to include the generate block to tell terragrunt to generate the backend block into a tf file to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way:

```
terragrunt = {
    terraform {
    source = "git::git@github.com:org/repo.git//lambda?ref=v0.6.2"
  }
}

    backend "s3" {
      bucket         = "stage-terraform"
      key            = "app/terraform.tfstate"
      region         = "us-east-1"
      encrypt        = false
      dynamodb_table = "stage-terraform-lock-table"
    }
```

Comment: yes, i tried doing something similar but it throws this error "You must define a backend block (it can be empty!)". Those tf modules managed by myself will have the backend block. but since i'm pointing the source to the git repo, it doesn't have it.

Comment: @JustStarted backend block should be defined in terragrunt file. Please see my answer

Comment: I've updated my original post. yes, I do have that in another file located in the parent folder. i'm wondering is it because the backend block doesn't exist in the main.tf file in the github repo? https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance/blob/master/main.tf

Comment: @JustStarted no, backend block not needed in the module in Github. Looks like you are doing everything correctly. Do you have any particular error?

Comment: Yes, the error state that I need to define the backend block. Could it be the "find_in_parent_folders()" isn't pointing to my outer terragrunt.hcl (1)?